# How to run sychronous tasks on IHost start up

Tags: .net-core, windows-services, console-application, startup

I am working with Windows Service that is a .Net Core Console application.
It contains an instance of an IHostedService which reads messages from a queue and processes them.
Before reading the messages I want to do a short database call and populate a cache.

How do I prevent the hosted service from starting until I have finished populating my cache?

The hostbuilder is currently configured like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services
                .AddHostedService<MessageProcessor>()
                .AddSingleton(provider => new ServiceBusClient(_connectionString))
                .AddSingleton<ICachePopulator, CachePopulator>()
        });

    hostBuilder.Build().Run();
}
```

I looked at the [IStartupFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.istartupfilter?view=aspnetcore-5.0) interface but it seems to be suitable for only ASP.Net Core services (please correct me if I'm wrong here).
I also looked at the [Startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0) class but it seems to be suitable for configuration only rather than synchronous tasks.

Comment: You could do it outside DI or you could do it as a hosted service if it's quick enough (they run sequentially, one after the other)

Comment: Ah right, I didn't realise they ran sequentially. Simply adding two Hosted Services works great.